# Is an achronal set contained in its own causal future?

Tags: general-relativity, topology, causality

I use Wald's notation: $I^+$ is the chronological future and $J^+$ is the causal future.

My confusion arises from the following passage in Wald (1984):

> Now, let $S$ be a closed, achronal set (possibly with edge). We define the *future domain of dependence* of $S$, denoted $D^+(S)$, by
>   $$D^+(S)=\{p\in M|\, \text{Every past inextendible causal curve through $p$ intersects $S$}\}$$
>   Note that we always have $S\subset D^+(S)\subset J^+(S)$.

I have to disagree with the last statement. We know that $S$ is achronal, i.e. $I^+(S)\cap S=\emptyset$. The relation $S\subset D^+(S)\subset J^+(S)$ implies $S\subset J^+(S)$, i.e. $J^+(S)\cap S\ne\emptyset.$ But I cannot see how a set can be both achronal and contained in its causal future. Hence the title of my question.

I *think* Wald meant to write $S\subset D^+(S)\subset \overline{J^+(S)}$. [EDIT: Disregard this statement.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the causal future of $p$ is the set of points joined to $p$ by timelike or null curves, and the constant path $\gamma(t) = p$ joining $p$ to $p$ itself has vanishing tangent vector and hence is a null curve (though a rather silly one), $p \in J^+(p)$, and so, $S \subset J^+(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

The causal relation $J$ is defined so as to be reflexive.
For instance, the causal future is defined as follows
$$
J^+(S)=\cup_{p\in S} J^+(p)
$$
where
$$
J^+(p)=\{q: q=p \textrm{ or  there is  a causal curve from } p \textrm{ to } q \}
$$
(this is really the commonly accepted definition). So it becomes clear that
$$
S=\cup_{p\in S}\{p\}\subset  \cup_{p\in S} J^+(p) \subset J^+(S).
$$
Usually by *causal curve* one understands a piecewise regular curve, so a constant curve is usually not seen as a causal curve, hence the definition of $J^+(p)$ give above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure I got it.

The causal future $J^+(p)$ of a point $p$ is defined as the set of all points $q$ connected by a future pointing timelike or null curve to $p$. I think the secret lies in that this is a closed set in Minkowski spacetime. To see this, we see that the curves connecting the points in $J^+(p)$ are the timelike curves (negative length) plus the null curves (zero length). Included in the set of null curves is the trivial curve connecting $p$ to $p$, which has zero length. Thus $J^+(p)$ is closed. Since $J^+(S)$ is just the union of all $J^+(p)$, $p\in M$, it is also closed. This means it contains $S$, because $S\cap\partial J^+(S)\ne\emptyset$ and $J^+(S)$ is closed. I think this generalizes nicely to a general spacetime, because even though $J^+(S)$ need no longer be closed, $S\cap\partial J^+(S)\ne\emptyset$ should still hold.

Comment: Careful, an infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed - just as an infinite intersection of open sets is not necessarily open, so you need another argument than just "$J^+(p)$ is closed" to conclude that $J^+(S)$ is closed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Are there any simple counterexamples? I'm not sure how to refine my argument.

Comment: Take the intervals $[0,1 - \frac{1}{n}]$. They are closed, but the union over all $n$ is $[0,1)$, which is neither open nor closed. I am not a home with causal sets, so I cannot tell you which way this argument is supposed to go.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: What if $S$ is compact? After all, $[0,1)$ is not compact IIRC.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: A more general question: What is the restriction needed on $\{U_i\}$ such that $\bigcup_iU_i$ is closed?

Comment: Any compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and closed, but this does not hold for all metric spaces, in particular, I think it indeed fails on Lorentzian manifolds. That said, I am confused what your actual question here is - you say, $S \subset J^+(S)$ doesn't make sense to you, and yet $J^+$ is the set of points joined by timelike or *null* curves, and the constant path joining $p$ to $p$ is a null curve, so $p \in J^+(p)$, and hence $S \subset J^+(S)$, right? Generally: Any finite union of closed sets is closed, but nothing else holds in arbitrary topologies.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Crap. After reading my question again I realize that I don't need $J^+(S)$ to be closed. Post your comment or whatever and I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks. Could you also please answer my more general question (comment above) in your answer? EDIT: Saw your edit.

Comment: Put it this way: every singleton $\{x\}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is closed, so if every union of closed sets were closed, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be closed (and open), $\mathbb{R}$ would be totally disconnected, and topology would be pointless: it could capture no notion of neighborhood. You need to put a limit on the number of at least one kind of set operation to get a meaningful definition of "open" and "toplogy". You've likely heard of $\sigma$-algebras: these are like topologies, but only allow countable unions and intersections.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Oh, cool. I never thought of it like that, and my understanding of topology has come a long way since February.

Comment: Yes topology is very cool. It amazes me how much you can get from such simple axioms - the flip side of that statement is, of course, that mathematicians spent a long time fine tuning the topology postulates, until they could build an axiomatic description of all the useful notions in analysis. It seems Urysohn and Alexandroff were particularly big names in this fine tuning exercise (people call them the heads of the Russian Point Set Topology School).